# spring official batch table relationship description seems wrong

Tags: spring-batch

The first thing I'd like to say is that I'm not a database expert.
I found something wrong that the structure of the batch table described in the following link.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html

[batch table relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3z17.png)

The BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE and BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION tables, /BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION and BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION tables have a non-identifying, one-to-many relationship that matches the content described in the below MySQL SQL link.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql

But isn't it correct that the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION and BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT tables must have a one-to-one relationship? (BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION and BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT too)

And I don't understand why BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS does not have primary key.

I humbly believe that this drawing must have been drawn by a professional
and that if many people saw this drawing and did not correct it, I would be wrong.

I created tables using schema-mysql.sql and get the picture drawing by other CASE tool,
It displays one-to-one relationship.

Is this wrong or am I?

Answer (score 0):

> isn't it correct that the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION and BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT tables must have a one-to-one relationship?

Each job execution has its own execution context, and an execution context belongs to a single job execution. So the relation should be one-to-one. The same is true for a step execution. The diagram should be updated. Please open an issue with a reference to this SO question and we will fix it.

> And I don't understand why BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS does not have primary key.

This is because job parameters have no identity, they are value objects. Therefore, the table does not have a primary key, but you can add one if you want. This won't alter the internal behaviour of the framework. This is explained in the appendix [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#metaDataBatchJobParams).